# Complex array ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have the following array:

```
var articles = [
     {
          id: 7989546,
          tags: [
              "98#6",
              "107#6",
              "558234#7"
          ]
     },
     //...
]
```

Each element of this array represents (partially) some kind of **content** in our website. It has an ***id*** and is tagged with ***people*** (#6) and/or ***topics*** (#7).

The user is going to be provided a cookie containing the suggested or recommended tags, like this:

```
var suggestions = [
     "46#6",
     "107#6",
     "48793#7"
]
```

Consider these tags like suggestions that will be shown to the end user, like *"Maybe you are interesed in reading..."*

The `suggestions` array is already ordered by **tag prioritiy**. This means, that the first tag is more relevant to the user than the second tag.

Now, what I want to do is to order my `articles` array in the same way, that is, by **tag priority**.

No filters should be applied as the `articles` array is guaranteed to have elements that have at least one tag from the `suggestions` array.

If I have an article with tags: `[ "98#6", "107#6", 558234#7" ]` and another one with tags: `[ "46#6", "36987#7" ]`, I want the latter to be first, because the tag `46#6` has more priority than `107#6` in the `suggestions` array.

How can I achieve this kind of ordering (using two arrays)?

**Note:** jQuery solutions are gladly accepted.

Comment: assuming your data size is not too big, you can always write a O(n^2) sorting method yourself, such as bubblesort or selection sort. that should easier take care of your need

Comment: slightly confused. "46#6" has a higher priority than "107#6". You're comparing the first index of one array to the second index of another array. Is that intended?

Comment: @ChristianHain "46#6" has more priority than "107#6" because "46#6" is at top of "107#6" in the `suggestions` array. However, you're kind of right when saying that the tag index on the `sugesstions` array defines its priority. The smaller the index, the higher the priority

Comment: How do you know that "46#6" at at top of "107#6". I don't understand why you're skipping "98#6"

Comment: @ChristianHain You should look at my `suggestions` array that I showed on the question. you can see that it has three elements in it: `[ "46#6", "107#6", "48793#7" ]`. `46#6` is first, and `107#6` is second, therefore `46#6` has more priority. I'm ignoring `"98#6"` because it is not in my `suggestions` array, and therefore it should be ignored when ordering

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Let me think about this...

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fkxagugz/)***

Just make your own sort function and then use `.indexOf` in order to check for tag existence. The issue that you are going to have to decide to handle on your own is what makes the most sense for collisions. If an article is tagged with a priority 1 tag, but another article is tagged with 3 lower priority tags, who gets precedence? There is some logic involved there and in my suggested solution I simply just take a total of the priority by using the length of suggestions and summing the priorities. This can be adapted to give a different type of collision detection if you wish, but the approach will be basically the same.

*Step 1: Create the compare function*

This is going to order the array descending base on the result from tagCount. Which is to say that if tagCount returns a value of 6 for right, and a value of 3 for left, then 6 is ordered first.

```
var compareFn = function(left,right){
    return tagCount(right.tags) - tagCount(left.tags);
};
```

*Step 2: Create the tagCount "algorithm" for determining priority*

This simply gives precedence to the earliest occurring match, but will also give some weight to multiple later occurring matches. It does this by taking the matched index subtracted from the length of the match array (suggestions). So if there are 5 suggestions, and the first suggestion is matched, then that is going to end up being a value of 5 (length=5 - index=0).

```
var tagCount = function(tags){    
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
        var weight = suggestions.indexOf(tags[i]);
        if(weight > -1) 
        count += tags.length - weight;
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

Stack Snippet

```js
var articles = [
     {
          id: 7989546,
          tags: [
              "107#6",
              "558234#7"
          ]
     },
     {
          id: 756,
          tags: [
              "98#6",
              "558234#7"
          ]
     },
     {
          id: 79876,
          tags: [
              "98#6",
              "107#6",
              "558234#7"
          ]
     },
     {
          id: 7984576,
          tags: [
              "98#6",
              "107#6",
              "46#6"
          ]
     }
];
var suggestions = [
     "46#6",
     "107#6",
     "48793#7"
];
var compareFn = function(left,right){
    return tagCount(right.tags) - tagCount(left.tags);
};
var tagCount = function(tags){    
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
     var weight = suggestions.indexOf(tags[i]);
     if(weight > -1) 
         count += tags.length - weight;
    }
    return count;
}
var a = articles.sort(compareFn);
console.log(a);
document.querySelector("#d").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(a);
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My approach: Sort by sum of relevance score**

Give you have:

```
var articles = [
     {
          id: 7989546,
          tags: [
              "98#6",
              "107#6",
              "558234#7"
          ]
     },
     {
          id: 8000000,
          tags: [
              "107#6",
              "107#10",
              "558234#7",
              "5555#1"
          ]
     },
     {
          id: 8333000,
          tags: [
              "46#6",
              "107#6",
              "666234#7",
              "107#6"
          ]
     }

];


var suggestions = [
     "46#6",
     "107#6",
     "48793#7"
];
```

And you want to sort `articles` by tags whereas tag ranks are defined in `suggestions`. One simple approach would be:

**Step 1)** For each article, get index of each tag exists in the `suggestion`. If it doesn't exist, discard.

> Given suggestions ["a","b","c"]
>
> Article tags ["a","b","zzzz","yyyy"]
>
> Will be mapped to index **[0,1]** (last two tags are discarded because they do not exist in suggestion list)

**Step 2)** Calculate degree of relevance. Higher-ranked tag (smaller index) yields greater value (see function `degreeOfRelevance()` below).

**Step 3)** Sum the total degree of relevance and sort by this value. Thus, the article which contains higher ranked tags (based on suggestions) will yield higher total score.

**Quick example:**

> article <100> with tags: [a,b,c]
>
> article <200> with tags: [b,c]
>
> article <300> with tags: [c,d,e,f]
>
> **Given suggestions:** [a,b,c]

The articles will be mapped to scores:

> article <100> index : [0,1] ===> sum score: 3+2 = 5
>
> article <200> index : [1] ===> sum score: 2
>
> article <300> index : [2] ===> sum score: 1
>
> **Therefore, the article <100> is ranked the most relevant document when sorted by score**

And below is the working code for this approach:

```
function suggest(articles, suggestions){
    function degreeOfRelavance(t){
        return suggestions.length - suggestions.indexOf(t); 
    }
    function weight(tags){
        return (tags.map(degreeOfRelavance)).reduce(function(a,b){
          return a+b
        },0);
    }
    function relatedTags(a){
        return a.tags.filter(function(t){
            return suggestions.indexOf(t)>=0
        });
    }
    
    articles.sort(function(a,b){
        return weight(relatedTags(a)) < weight(relatedTags(b))
    });
    return articles;
}

// See the output
console.log(suggest(articles,suggestions));
```